# oidc-client-js not showing all profile claims that oidc-client-js does

Tags: javascript, typescript, oauth, openid

If I use the following config object to instantiate UserManager on the oidc-client-ts typescript module:

```
  var config = {
    authority: "https://localhost:3000",
    client_id: "js",
    redirect_uri: "https://localhost:3001/callback.html",
    response_type: "code",
    scope: "openid profile IdentityServerApi colour", 
    post_logout_redirect_uri: "https://localhost:3001/index.html",
  }
```

calling usermanager.getUser comes back with a user object with the following profile claims:

```
  {
    "iss": "https://localhost:3000",
    "iat": 1681658331,
    "exp": 1681658631,
    "aud": "js",
    "sid": "E5E4621779C8970433CEE2E6472FF8DE",
    "sub": "cc23a1a1-a8ff-4caf-8fef-555d98923b8a",
    "idp": "local"
  }
```

If I use the same config with oidc-client-js I get this profile object

```
  {
    "amr": [
      "pwd"
    ],
    "sid": "32A90BF8B0EBF7780BC9B8E0AD3DDE8B",
    "sub": "cc23a1a1-a8ff-4caf-8fef-555d98923b8a",
    "auth_time": 1681659272,
    "idp": "local",
    "name": "theadmin@email.com",
    "preferred_username": "theadmin@email.com",
    "favorite_colour": "FAVORITECOLOUR_DEFAULT"
  }
```

I have tried updating the config to include the following values as the documentation for them suggests that with these values I might get the result im looking for but they seem to make no difference to what is being returned

```
  {
    ...
    client_authentication: "client_secret_post",
    loadUserInfo: true,
    mergeClaims: true,
    filterProtocolClaims: false
  }
```

My authorization enpoint is showing that when using the ts module my userClaims are being requested twise upon login (once on redirect back to the client calback page and second on the call to getUser after being redirected back to the client home page)
However with the js module they are being requested 3 times (all during the first redirect back to the client)

is the problem in the config used to set up the UserManager or the redirect or what?

this is the config im using for UserManager on the client callback page:

```
  {
    authority: "https://localhost:3000", 
    response_mode: "query", 
    client_id: "js",
    redirect_uri: "https://localhost:3001/callback.html",
  }
```

Forgive my ignorance about oAuth, I want to use the new ts version but I have no idea why one is displaying completely different profile data to the other with the same configuration info.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like writing this question out has helped me to figure the answer to this.

turns out I needed to include loaduserinfo to the usermanagerSettings config object on the callback page:

```
  {
    ....
    loadUserInfo: true,
  })
```

Just going to keep this question in case anyone else has this issue. Was a bit difficult to figure out